# onCompletion(mp: MediaPlayer?) is unintentionally called after USB storage is connected

Tags: android, kotlin, usb, android-mediaplayer

I am making Android application that displays contents that is copied from USB storage disk.

The problem is when USB storage disc is connected to device, Media Player `onCompletion()` is immediately called although movie now playing is not finished yet.

I want to fix this problem not to call `onCompletion()` when USB is connected.

Thanks in advance.

```kotlin
class PlayerViewModel(application: Application, repository: GCSRepository) : ViewModel(), USBDownloadListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    override fun onDownloadFinished(unusedFiles: MutableSet<String>) {
        // some codes here...
    }

    override fun onCompletion(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        // some codes here...
    }

}
```

```kotlin
class USBIOManager(context: Context) {
    init {
        registerReceiver(context)
    }

   private fun registerReceiver(context: Context) {
        unRegisterReceiver(context)
        mUsbReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
               // some codes here...
               updateUSBFiles(context)
               // some codes here...
            }
        }
   }
    private fun updateUSBFiles(context: Context) {
        // some codes here...
        downloadListener?.onDownloadFinished(existingInternalStorageFiles)
        // some codes here...
    }
```

```kotlin
interface USBDownloadListener {
     fun onDownloadFinished(unusedFiles : MutableSet<String>)
}
```